# Creating Array of Dictionary in Swift

Tags: swift

I am new to **Swift**. I am trying to create an array of dictionary.

```
var items: [Dictionary<String,Int>] = []
var dict1 = ["One" : 1, "Two" : 2 ]
var dict2 = ["Three" : 3, "Four" : 4]
var dict3 = ["Five" : 5 , "Six" : 5]

items[0] = dict1
items[1] = dict2
items[2] = dict3
items
```

But it is not getting initialized properly. Playground shows no error but it is not taking dict2 and dict 3. What is wrong with it. Please correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the console (⇧⌘Y), you can see the error

> fatal error: Array index out of range

You should use `items.append(dict1)` or `items.insert(dict1, atIndex: 0)` instead of `items[0] = ...`.

Comment: I have checked the console, no error is there. And why array index out of range error should be there. I am putting the elements in array contagiously. However items.append() worked for me. But can u explain me what was wrong with my way.

Comment: Subscript assignment syntax can't be used to add items to an array in Swift (apparently). That's what `append` is for. Or, you can use `insert(_:atIndex:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 items.append(dict1)
 items.append(dict2)
 and so on...
```