# Convert Dictionary to Array<Dictionary> in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have two dictionaries and want to convert them to an `Array` of `Dictionary`.

Updated Answer:

```
var items: [[String: Any]] = []

let dict:[String: Any] = ["latitude": 11.91756,"activity_type": "Flying", "offline": false,"longitude": 87.66988, "accuracy": 0, "actual_speed": 0]
 let dict1:[String: Any] = ["encoded": "uvymA{cayMejhilzA?aC", "activity_type": "Walking", "offline": false]

items.append(dict1)
items.append(dict)

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: items, options: [])
let decoded = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!

[{"encoded":"uvymA{cayMejhilzA?aC","activity_type":"Walking","offline":false},{"latitude":11.91756,"activity_type":"Flying","offline":false,"longitude":87.669880000000006,"accuracy":0,"actual_speed":0}]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623505/creating-array-of-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: Have I understood correctly that you have two `Dictionary` values and that you want to create an `Array` that contain both of those dictionaries?

Comment: Please explain what it is you want to do, do you have some code so far to help us understand the question better?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Whats up with `let jsonDict = [dict, dict1]`?

Comment: @ZGski i have done , found the result

Answer (score 0):

```
var dictionaryArray: [[String : Any?]] = [[:]]
```

After that you can `append` as many dictionaries as you want

Comment: This will add an empty dictionary to your array.

Comment: @LeoDabus        [[:], ["encoded": Optional("uvymA{cayMejhilzA?aC"), "activity_type": Optional("Walking"), "offline": Optional(false)], ["latitude": Optional(11.91756), "activity_type": Optional("Flying"), "offline": Optional(false), "longitude": Optional(87.669880000000006), "accuracy": Optional(0), "actual_speed": Optional(0)]]

Comment: @ios `var dictionaries:[[String:Any]] = []`

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your object type Dictionary to [String: Any]. You can replace the below code.

```
let dict:[String: Any] = ["latitude": 11.91756,"activity_type": "Flying", "offline": false,"longitude": 87.66988, "accuracy": 0, "actual_speed": 0]
let dict1:[String: Any] = ["encoded": "uvymA{cayMejhilzA?aC", "activity_type": "Walking", "offline": false]

var arrayDict = [[String: Any]]()
arrayDict.append(dict)
arrayDict.append(dict1)
```